# Counting the number of divisions until the sum == 0

Tags: java

So I'm trying to divide a number by 2 repeatedly until the sum hits 0.
For example, dividing 40 by two, it will be like this 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0, and it will print 6, because it divided 6 times.

The code I came up with is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter A Number:");
    try {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        int j = i;
        int k = j/2; //sum

        while (k == 0) {
            System.out.println(k);
            k++;
        }
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("done");
    }

}
```

}

I know it's very wrong, but if someone can point me into the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Please read the linked article and [edit] according to its advice - this question is **impossible to answer** as written.

Comment: Note that the fact that all of the answers show *the entire code* to solve this is proof that the article I linked to is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I missed something but the solution seems quite trivial:

```
int i = sc.nextInt();
int count = 0;
while (i > 0)
{
  i /= 2;
  count++;
}
```

I'm not sure what "until the sum hits 0" means.

Comment: Since `j/2` is commented as `//sum` , it is probably just the result of the division, so your answer looks good .

Answer (score 0):

This is not kinda "algorithmic" solution but you may achieve what you need using the following approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter A Number:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(Integer.SIZE-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(sc.nextInt()));
}
```